# How to implement Breeze with NHibernate and webapi 2

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm trying to implement some days Breeze in my project with NHibernate and webapi 2 but without success.
[Examples on github](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/tree/master/Samples/NorthBreeze/NorthBreeze) are for webapi 1

I'm having several problems, among them:

1. Not exist BreezeNHController in webapi 2
2. With IUnitOfWork architecture, ContextProvider was confused.

I tried to add the attribute `BreezeController` to the controller but to perform the action `{{odata}}/GruposUsuarios?$filter=substringof('Vivo', Nome)` still having trouble translating the query.

The main objective is to use Breeze to perform queries using odata queries as `substringof` and `expand`.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I create a sample project in https://gitlab.com/problems/breezenhibernateproblem/tree/master

Comment: I managed solve the problem with webapi 1.0.

Following sample code https://gitlab.com/problems/breezenhibernateproblem/commits/hotfix-breeze-webapi1

Comment: Hi, we had also some problems with breeze,nhibernate and webapi2(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562850/breeze-sorting-by-navigation-property-fails-with-nhibernate-and-webapi-2). There are other issues with NHibernate. The breeze nhibernate specialist will be back on january...

Comment: Right now, we reverted to webapi v1 and almost everything works.

Answer (score 1):

The [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.WebApi2.NH/) is now available, and the [NorthBreeze sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/northbreeze) 
is now updated to use Breeze 1.4.8 and WebApi 2

With this update, your queries should be working in Web Api 2.  Please let me know if they are not.  Thanks.